# 3-SAT for variables appearing 3 times

Tags: np-complete, 3-sat

I've been trying to investigate 3-SAT for variables appearing 3 times and so far I'm getting some mixed answers as to its complexity.

For example, https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/scott/Papers/restricted3sat.pdf says

> instances of 3-SAT in which every variable occurs three times are
>   always satisfiable (this is an immediate corollary of Hall’s Theorem),
>   while it is NP-hard to decide the satisfiability of 3-SAT instances in
>   which every variable occurs four times

so apparently when variables appear 3 times it's an easy problem (?).

But the following two references seem to say something else:

From here, http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~lyuu/complexity/2008a/20080403.pdf,

> 3sat is NP-complete for expressions in which each variable is
>   restricted to appear at most three times, and each literal at most
>   twice.

and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.319.8796&rep=rep1&type=pdf Lemma 5:

> The  SAT-3  problem  is  NP-complete  even  when  each  variable 
>   appears  3  times.

So is this problem NP-complete for when variables appear 3 times or 4 times? I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Just be careful what 3-SAT means: clauses of length at most 3, or exactly 3. If there are exactly 3 literals in every clause, the instance is always satisfiable (IIRC from Tovey's paper). Otherwise, the problem is NP-complete (you also allow for smaller clauses).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no conflict between your references. The problem is that they have slightly different definitions of what 3-SAT is. You need to read the (original) theorems by Tovey very carefully.

> Let r,s-SAT denote the class of instances with exactly r variables per
>   clause and at most s occurrences per variable.
>
> [...]
>
> **Theorem 2.1.** Boolean satisfiability is NP-complete when restricted to instances with *2 or 3* variables per clause and at most 3 occurrences per variable.
>
> [...]
>
> **Theorem 2.4.** Every instance of r,r-SAT is satisfiable.

The reason there's no conflict is that you need to allow 2 *or* 3 literals per clause to make 3-SAT $NP$-complete when restricted to at most 3 occurrences per variable. The trivially satisfiable bit only kicks in when you have exactly 3 literals per clause and at most 3 occurrences per variable.

Comment: Ah ok, so in my last reference, for example, the definition of 3-SAT would have to be "instances with clauses of at most 3 literals" instead of "instances with exactly 3 literals" because the latter definition would lead to automatic satisfiability if each variable appears at most 3 times, right?

Comment: What about 3 occurrences in total and no limit of literals in a clause? Is it also NP-Complete?